# How to plot gamma distribution with k and theta as parameters in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, probability

I am trying to plot(using matplotlib) the pdf of gamma distribution with parameters k and theta. However, all functions I found on the net, such as scipy.stat.gamma or sympy.stats.Gamma, are using a and scale as parameters. Does anyone know how I can use those functions? Or is there any way I can get the pdf of gamma function of specific k and theta in python?

Comment: It would be helpful if you clarified the meaning of your "theta" parameter.  For example, on the [gamma distribution wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution), theta *is* the scale parameter.  I suspect you want to use the "rate" parameter (called beta on the wikipedia page).  beta is just 1/theta.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser On the wiki page, there is a plot on the right-hand side the some parameters k and theta. I think theta parameter means the scale parameter as you said, but I'm not sure if it has the same meaning as the scale parameter in scipy.stats.gamma...

Comment: SciPy's `scale` parameter is the same as the parameter θ in the wikipedia page.  One thing to be aware of is that the SciPy implementation also has a location parameter, `loc`.  The distribution described in the wikipedia page corresponds to `loc = 0`.